# How can I determine which type of magnet I have?

Tags: electromagnetism

I have a very powerful permanent magnet and I am trying to determine which type it is (Hard Ferrite, Alnico, etc.) Are there any characteristics which would give away the type? Are there any experiments I can run (such as measuring the strength) which would allow me to deduce the type?

It has some orange corrosion (looks very much like iron rust). I do not have access to the magnet right now so I can't say exactly what the color is, but I will update the question with that information as soon as I can.

Answer (score 1):

you can check its density to roughly determine the type of magnet you have,
additionally you could also check its physical appearance and match it with other types.